# How to escape '-' character in console/command line

Tags: unix, command-line, console, command-line-arguments

I have a file named `-`. How to pass the file name as an argument to console commands ?.

I mean is there a way to escape `-` character in console ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can prepend a path to it, for example:

```
cat ./-
```

David A Wheeler has written an [in-depth essay](http://www.dwheeler.com/essays/filenames-in-shell.html) on the subject of how to handle file names in shell scripts.

Answer (score 0):

For some commands, I know you can say it is the end of the parameters on the command line with a double `-`.

e.g.:

```
touch -
rm -- -
rm: Remove -? y
```